# Want To Exec command To Solr

Tags: php, solr

this Is My Code In View

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="USER_ID_LOGING" name="USER_ID_LOGIN" action="<?php echo base_url('feed_admin/feed_submit') ?>" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPass" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Feed</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_feed" name="input_feed" value="<?php echo set_value('input_feed'); ?>" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"> input Feed </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

this is controller

```
  function feed_submit(){
$this->form_validation->set_rules('input_feed','feed','required');
if($this->form_validation->run() == true)
{
  $feedlink = $this->input->post("input_feed");
  $solr_check ="dir";
  $solr_directory="cd C:\solr";
  $solr_dir = passthru("$solr_directory $solr_check" );
  echo $solr_dir;
}
```

My Problem Is I want To execute Command To Cd To Another Floder like This

cd C:\solr and add new feed To solr

Thank you For your answer

Comment: Any reason why you're not using a proper Solr library? Your code example doesn't do anything useful. How are you adding feeds to Solr? What is "adding a feed"? How are you fetching the data you're inserting into Solr?

Comment: I want to use in my website and add feeds function in website so requirement is implement feeds from solr to my website, my website is
system admin